# Goutte Symfony Domcrawler open js modal!?

Tags: javascript, symfony, goutte, domcrawler

i am using the Goutte (Symfony Dom)crawler which is not able to fire js and open a modal.

Its a silly question but are there any extensions for Goutte. Can I get access to a modal. What would you suggest?

I would be thankful for any answer.

Comment: If the modal is not loaded via AJAX, then yes it is possible. Just access it as you would any other element.

Comment: The modal is loaded via AJAX. What can I do?

Comment: If you have the url of the loaded HTML you can just crawl this page and not the main page. The HTML has to come from somewhere.